# Is ZeroMQ server listening infinitely?

Tags: java, client-server, message-queue, zeromq

I am trying to implement client server using ZeroMQ.

I am running a server in an infinite loop, bound to a socket and polling the the socket infinitely.

When a client sends a request, the server receives only for the first time. The subsequent requests are not received by the server, below is my code snippet

Server :

```
        ZMQ.Socket socket = context.socket(ZMQ.REP);
        socket.bind ("tcp://*:5555");
        System.out.println("Server is in receive mode");
            while (!Thread.currentThread ().isInterrupted ()) {           
                Poller poller = new Poller(1);
                poller.register(socket, Poller.POLLIN);
                poller.poll();
                if (poller.pollin(0)) {
                    ZMsg zmqMessage = ZMsg.recvMsg(socket);                 
                    if (zmqMessage!=null) {
                        zmqMessage.getFirst().getData();
                    }
                }
```

Client :

```
    ZMQ.Socket socket = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");
    ZMsg readyFrame = new ZMsg();
    readyFrame.add(new ZFrame("READY"));
    readyFrame.send(socket);
```

I tried poll out in client side like below but it did not work.

```
        Poller poller = new Poller(1);
        poller.register(socket, Poller.POLLOUT);
        poller.pollout(0);
```

Comment: @user3666197, thanks, it's really nice served my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZeroMQ is a wonderfull piece of art from Pieter HINTJENS' and Martin SUSTRIK's team. Yes, there are some low-level, technology-related issues, that still require some design efforts, nevertheless the ZeroMQ is stable and very mature.

### System thinking - the toys are working as distributed automata

Yes, normal work-flow of `SEQ` programming languages, that work serially ( or "just"-concurrent ) suddenly gets new dimension - a distributed automata dimension.

So the local workflow is dependent on externally operated parties.

This is the case for each of the ZeroMQ Formal Communication Patterns' primitive archetypes bear human-familiar names:

> *one* **`REQ`**-*ests, second* **`REP`**-*lies*
> *one* **`PUB`**-*lishes, anyone* **`SUB`**-*scribes to just listen*
> *one* **`PUSH`**-*es, the other* **`PULL`**-*s to receive*
> *each party, bound together in* **`PAIR`** *may both speak and listen, whenever, as needed*
> etc for **`BROKER`**, **`DEALER`**, **`XPUB`**, **`XSUB`**, et al

This is the **by-design** reason, why your server-side **`REQ`**-archetype behaviour will not receive any next message from any other party ( yes, there might be more clients connected to the same `REQ`-transport-class node ), until it indeed `REP`-lies ( be it an empty message or not ) to the **`REP`**-side of the distributed automata.

### The best next step

Well, the best next step one may ever do in going professional in this direction is IMHO to get a bit more global view, which may sound complicated for the first few things one tries to code with ZeroMQ, but if you **[at least jump to the page 265](https://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main:files/cc1pe.pdf)** of the [**[Code Connected, Volume 1]** [available asPdf >>>  http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3Afiles/cc1pe.pdf ]](https://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main:files/cc1pe.pdf), if it were not the case of reading step-by-step thereto.

The fastest-ever learning-curve would be to have first an un-exposed view on the **Fig.60** *Republishing Updates* and **Fig.62** *HA Clone Server pair for a possible High-availability approach* and then go back to the roots, elements and details.

### Overheads:

As a minor note, it would be fair and resource-wise to lower the processing overheads once the Poller would be created "outside" the `while(){}`-loop, as there is no visible reason for reinstating such element and re-register it's services for each loop again and again:

```
Poller poller      = new Poller(1);                  // new INSTANCE
poller.register( socket, Poller.POLLIN );            // pay COSTS of SETUP
                                                     //     JUST ONCE, HERE
while ( !Thread.currentThread ().isInterrupted () ) {// inf LOOP

    poller.poll();                                   //     POLL !BLOCKING
    if ( poller.pollin( 0 ) ) {                      //     if ITEMS{ ... proc 'em }
    ZMsg zmqMessage  = ZMsg.recvMsg( socket );
    if ( zmqMessage != null )
         zmqMessage.getFirst().getData();
    }
}
```

### Anyway:  Enjoy the worlds of distributed computing!

Answer (score 1):

A `REP` socket must send a reply before it can receive again.
If you're just wanting a 1 way communication you might be better using a `PUB` & `SUB`.